# gnuplot with errorbars plotting

Tags: plot, gnuplot

The data in my "file.txt" file are as in the following (sample row shown)

```
31 1772911000 6789494.2537881
```

Note that the second column is the mean and the third is the standard deviation of my
input sample. So, for the error bar, I would need the bar at the x axis value 31, with the error bar start at (second column value)-(third column value), and end at (second column value)+(third column value). I tried the following:

```
plot "file.txt" using ($1-$2):1:($2+$1) with errorbars
```

but the result is inappropriate. Any help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need x:y:err, so try

```
plot "file.txt" using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars
```

[image: yerrorbars]

You may instead want candlesticks. These are generally a box with error bars extending out of the top and bottom, but setting the mins and maxes the same should give you boxes of the required size:

```
plot "file.txt" using 1:($2-$3):($2-$3):($2+$3):($2+$3) with candlesticks
```

[image: candlesticks]

Comment: Thanks. The first worked, but the second produced     gnuplot> set style boxplot candlesticks                                                            ^
         expecting 'data', 'function', 'line', 'fill' or 'arrow'

gnuplot>

Comment: @user506901 -- It looks (to me from the gnuplot docs) that you would just need `plot "file.txt" using ... with candlesticks` -- I'm not sure what Phil H was doing with `set style boxplot candlesticks` ... (I'm using gnuplot 4.4.2), maybe this behavior has changed in 4.6?

Comment: @mgilson: You're right, I was trusting my understanding of the help file, I don't use candlesticks often enough to remember. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @PhilH -- the offending line `set style boxplot candlesticks` is still there ;-) -- You'll want to remove that line as well.

Answer (score 7):

you can also try:

```
plot "file.txt" using 1:2:($2-$3):($2+$3) with errorbars
```

($2-$3) is y error bar low value, and ($2+$3) is y error bar high value

However, I think that you should use standard error = standard deviation / square root (sample size), instead of standard deviation, to compute error bars.

Comment: Whether to use standard deviation, standard error, or 95% confidence interval for the error bars depends on what you want to convey with your plot. See e.g. a discussion in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2064100/) from Journal of Cell Biology.