# Plot from two files with errorbars for Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am thinking which way to do the addition of errorbars better by thinking the format of data. 
The standard way of adding errors bars is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10684182/54964), for instance.

My original data is in ranges

```
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing 
2025 73-78 80-85 87-92 
2035 63-68 80-85 97-107 
2050 42-57 75-90 104.5-119.5
```

where the values are ranges. 
I cannot plot directly in Gnuplot so I have to split it to averages and to error values in two files:

Averages:

```
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5
2035 65.5 82.5 102
2050 49.5 82.5 112
```

and error configuration in ybar

```
Model Decreasing Constant Increasing
2025 2.5 2.5 2.5
2035 2.5 2.5 5
2050 7.5 7.5 7.5
```

I normally plot data like this as a one file

```
plot for [i=2:4] 'data.dat' using 1:i w linespoints
```

but now I should go through two files at the same time while doing the plot. 
The normal syntax of plotting errorbars is

```
plot 'data' using 1:2:0:($1+$3):4:5 with yerrorlines
```

and manual [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/mgr.html).

**How can you plot from two files with errorbars in Gnuplot?** 
Feel free to propose if you know better way to do the addition of these errorbars in gnuplot.

### Output to Cristoph's answer

[image]

where error bars missing in the first and third points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot 5 supports that you specify several characters as data file separators.

So, if you are sure you'll never get negative values (which I hopen given the format of your data), then you can use your original data file and set both white space and hyphen as datafile separator:

```
set datafile separator " -"
plot for [i=2:6:2] "data" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerrorlines
```

Comment: I added the output of this command to the question body. I do not get error bars for the first and third points.

Comment: Because they lie on the border. Add an `set offset 1,1,0,0` and you'll see the error bars for all points.

Comment: So this offset sets one unit offsets to x-axis in both directions and nothing to y-axis. Now, I get the correct errorbars. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wonder about your columns used for plotting `with yerrorlines`. If your first data for 2025 is 75.5+/-2.5, you usually plot it with

```
plot "datafile" using <xcolum>:<ycolum>:<yerrorcolumn>
```

Your six columns are for the case of xy errorbars and specify the point itself and  the lower and upper absolute values in x and y. But may be you are just doing it as you need it...

Now back to your question:
Gnuplot can *not* handle data from two files simultaneously, i.e. it can not take xy-values from one file and y-errors from another.

If you're running linux, the command line tool `join` can help.
Your averages stored in file A and the errors in file B, `join A B` will concatenate lines with the same value in the first colum like this:

```
2025 75.5 82.5 89.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
```

So,

```
plot "<join A B" using 1:2:5 with yerrorlines
```

should do the job. (`"<join A B"` will call the join command in the background and read its output like a data file)

Comment: I have currently BSD Join. Which join do you mean?

Comment: Well, try it! I guess it does just the same job. In this context, I meant any kind of linux/unix/bsd, may be even mac os. Finally, `join` could also be made available for win.

Comment: I opened a new thread about BSD Find here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/181602/15504