# Fit many pieces of data in Gnuplot's for loop

Tags: for-loop, plot, gnuplot

Data

```
Model Decreasing-err Constant-err Increasing-err
2025 73-78 80-85 87-92 
2035 63-68 80-85 97-107 
2050 42-57 75-90 104.5-119.5
```

which data-structure (use of -err) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29748320/54964).

To plot the points, I run

```
set terminal qt size 560,270; 
set grid; set offset 1,1,0,0; 
set datafile separator " -"; 
set key autotitle columnhead;
plot for [i=2:6:2] "data.dat" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerror;
```

and get

[image]

However, I would like to add a line fits to these points which you cannot do just with `with yerrorlines` because of kinks.

My pseudocode for fitting the increasing and decreasing lines

```
inc(x) = k1*x + k2; 
con(x) = n1*x + n2;
dec(x) = m1*x + m2;
fit inc(x), con(x) dec(x) for [i=2:6:2] "data.dat" 
   using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) 
   via k1,k2,n1,n2,m1,m2;
```

where the problem is in using the function `fit` with for loop.

**How can you use Gnuplot's fit in a for loop?** 
I would like to fit many lines at the same time to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `do` in conjunction with `eval` to do this:

```
# Define your functions (you can also use do + eval to do this)
f1(x) = a1*x+b1
f2(x) = a2*x+b2
f3(x) = a3*x+b3

# Loop
do for [i=1:3] {
eval sprintf("fit f%g(x) 'data.dat' u 0:%g via a%g, b%g", i, i, i, i)
}
```

You can adapt the above to your own purposes.

Comment: How do you run this as one-liner? I run `f1(x) = a1*x+b1; f2(x) = a2*x+b2; f3(x) = a3*x+b3; do for [i=1:3] { eval sprintf("fit f%g(x) model1_range.dat' u 0:%g via a%g, b%g, i, i, i, i) }`. But it stays in the prompt *more*.

Comment: @Masi You are missing a single quote before your data file name and a double quote at the end of the string.

Comment: I still get the same `f1(x) = a1*x+b1; f2(x) = a2*x+b2; f3(x) = a3*x+b3; do for [i=1:3] { eval sprintf("fit f%g(x) 'model1_range.dat' u 0:%g via a%g, b%g, i, i, i, i) }`, staying in the prompt *more*.

Comment: You still have a double quote missing at the end of the string: it should be `b%g",` instead of `b%g,`.