# Why keys fail in the latest Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

The code of the thread [Why autotitle wrong in this Gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29728922/54964) works in the old Gnuplot (19.4.2015), but fails in the newest, Ubuntu 15.10 and OS X 10.11.2. 
Data

```
Model Decreasing-err Constant-err Increasing-err 
2025 73-78 80-85 87-92 
2035 63-68 80-85 97-107 
2050 42-57 75-90 104.5-119.5
```

Code originally based on Christoph's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727673/54964)

```
set terminal qt size 560,270; 
set grid; set offset 1,1,0,0; 
set datafile separator " -"; 
set key autotitle columnhead;
plot for [i=2:6:2] "model1_range.dat" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerrorlines;
```

Output in Ubuntu 15.10 *Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 6* where two keys are missed having two times the warning `warning: Cannot find or open the file "model1_range_linear.dat"` so two missed error bars

[image]

Output is the three warnings and `No data in plot` without any error bar in OS X 10.11.2 with *Gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1*. 
I cannot understand the heterogeneous behavior between the two systems and the version 4/2015 of Gnuplot.

---

Why do keys fail the latest Gnuplot?

Comment: Is it only on qt terminal? I can't reproduce on my osx (same version) since I don't have the qt terminal I tested on x11, and I get the three lines.

Comment: @bibi Unbelievable that the problem/bug would be in Qt terminal. Can you please send your output as an answer with exact details of your system (gnuplot version, os).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I type:

```
08:26 ~ > cat test.txt 
Model Decreasing-err Constant-err Increasing-err 
2025 73-78 80-85 87-92 
2035 63-68 80-85 97-107 
2050 42-57 75-90 104.5-119.5
```

and then gnuplot installe via `brew install gnuplot --with-pdflib-lite --with-x11 --with-cairo`

```
08:26 ~ > gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'x11'
gnuplot> show version long

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
Compile options:
-READLINE  +LIBREADLINE  +HISTORY  
-BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY  +BINARY_DATA  
+GD_PNG  +GD_JPEG  +GD_TTF  +GD_GIF  +ANIMATION  
-USE_CWDRC  +X11  +X11_POLYGON  +MULTIBYTE  +X11_EXTERNAL +USE_MOUSE  +HIDDEN3D_QUADTREE  
+DATASTRINGS  +HISTOGRAMS  +OBJECTS  +STRINGVARS  +MACROS  +THIN_SPLINES  +IMAGE  +USER_LINETYPES +STATS +EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS 
MAX_PARALLEL_AXES=7

GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR = "/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.1/libexec/gnuplot/5.0"
GNUPLOT_PS_DIR     = "/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.1/share/gnuplot/5.0/PostScript"
HELPFILE           = "/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.0.1/share/gnuplot/5.0/gnuplot.gih"
gnuplot> set grid; set offset 1,1,0,0;  
gnuplot> set datafile separator " -"; 
gnuplot> set key autotitle columnhead;
gnuplot> plot for [i=2:6:2] "test.txt" using 1:(0.5*(column(i)+column(i+1))):(0.5*(column(i+1)-column(i))) with yerrorlines; 
gnuplot>
```

[image: and this is the result]

hope it helps!

Comment: My mistake was that qt5 missed completely from my systems. I thought that the dependencies would be installed automatically by installing gnuplot with qt. But no. And no clear warning that qt missing from the system.